# Simple Property System

Tags: c++

I have run into a small design predicament. It's not really a "problem" per se, it's just bothering me that I cannot find a cleaner solution :) and I was hoping some of you might have some good ideas or alternative solutions.

Say I have some pieces of data that can arrive on a communications channel (serial/IP, e.t.c) out of sync and at any time. The individual pieces of data are small, say ints or floats. They relate to some state of the machine sending the data. I wan't to design a simple "property" system, where I am alerted when a single data-item is received, or, when MULTIPLE data items have been received. For example, a single alert would be given to me, when I successfully collected two ints and a float.

Lets say the remote system can send me this:

```
DATA1 : float
DATA2 : int
DATA3 : int
DATA4 : double
DATA5 : short
```

Now, in pseudo-code, what I want to do is something like this (using macros or whatever)

```
PROPERTY(DATA1)
PROPERTY(DATA2, DATA3)
PROPERTY(DATA4)
```

that is, each property monitors a variable amount of data chunks, and sends me a SINGLE alert, when all of the pieces being monitored has changed/been filled.

At the moment I am using sigc++ which I think is a brilliant callback library. I have a working implementation, but it's cumbersome to code, because C++ does not really support variable argument lists, in the way that I want, so what I have done so far, is to have a single class, PROPERTY, which has a number of overloaded constructors, supporting 1 to X number of arguments, which is not really "dynamic". If I need more variables monitored, I need to make sure there is a constructor to handle the number of arguments.

Maybe it's just me trying to over-design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write a `Property` class that stores a collection of data chunks. Each chunk is either a [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) or some type of union, or a pointer to an an object that implements a data chunk interface.

The class could be initialized like

```
Property p;
p.addInt(xI).addFloat(xF).addShort(xS);
```

or like

```
Property p = { IntVal(xI), FloatVal(xF), ShortVal(xS) };
```

if a C++0x initializer list can be used, where `IntVal` etc. are wrappers that convert a more primitive data chunk type to the variant type used in the `Property` collection.

Comment: It's possible to make that construction-time by defining helper class, that will collect the arguments (to some collection) and passing that to the Property. Like `Property p(PropList().addInt(xI).addFloat(xF))`. (In C++03, that is, initializer lists are easier in C++11).

Comment: Nice, this solution seems clean! Easy to write, easy to expand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about some sort of serial communications here, so you must have some mechanism that tells your program what the data about to come down that serial line are. Otherwise, how can you distinguish two 32 bit integers from a double or from an array of eight chars?

That suggests making a class for each message type subclassed from some base message type. If your messages are very simple in nature (e.g., they comprise an integer, two integers, a double) you might be able to get away with a union or something similar, but you will still need some key that indicates which element of the union is applicable.

The handler that collects the incoming messages can be a nasty, complex beast. I've seen some (I did not write such a beast) with a cyclomatic complexity of 500+.